# Mapping length of dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

so I have a dictionary with mapped values e.g.

```
{'United States': LA, NY, LV, 'China': SZ, BJ}
```

How would I create a new dictionary that maps the country to the number of values it contains?

Would it then be possible for me to order this dictionary based on the number of values it contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using `collections.OrderedDict` object and `sorted` function:

```
d = {'United States': ['LA', 'NY', 'LV'], 'China': ['SZ', 'BJ']}
for k in d: 
    d[k] = len(d[k])

countryCodes = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))

print(countryCodes)
```

The output:

```
OrderedDict([('China', 2), ('United States', 3)])
```